# Default Scale value of Number column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes

[Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832) mentioned that the default precision value is 38 and scale is 0.

> If a precision is not specified, the column stores values as given. If
> no scale is specified, the scale is zero.

But the table mentioned there (Table 26-1) contradicts the statement.

```
 Input Data   | Specified As  | Stored As  

 7,456,123.89 |  NUMBER       | 7456123.89
```

If the default scale is 0 (number of digits to the right of the decimal point) then how come the above number is stored with 2 decimal digits. i.e. **.89**
or have I totally misunderstood the default scale concept?

Answer (score 1):

It might be more helpful to consider four different cases:

- No precision or scale `NUMBER`
- Precision and no scale `NUMBER(9)`
- Both precision and scale `NUMBER(9,2)`
- Scale only `NUMBER(*,2)`

The quote ...

```
If no scale is specified, the scale is zero.
```

... refers to the second of those, in which a precision but no scale is specified, not the first.